# tm package error "Cannot convert DocumentTermMatrix into normal matrix since vector is too large"

Tags: r, tm

I have created a DocumentTermMatrix that contains 1859 documents (rows) and 25722 (columns). In order to perform further calculations on this matrix I need to convert it to a regular matrix. I want to use the `as.matrix()` command. However, it returns the following error: cannot allocate vector of size 364.8 MB.

```
> corp
A corpus with 1859 text documents
> mat<-DocumentTermMatrix(corp)
> dim(mat)
[1]  1859 25722
> is(mat)
[1] "DocumentTermMatrix"
> mat2<-as.matrix(mat)
Fehler: kann Vektor der Größe 364.8 MB nicht allozieren # cannot allocate vector of size 364.8 MB
> object.size(mat)
5502000 bytes
```

For some reason the size of the object seems to increase dramatically whenever it is transformed to a regular matrix. How can I avoid this?

Or is there an alternative way to perform regular matrix operations on a DocumentTermMatrix?

Answer (score 10):

The quick and dirty way is to export your data into a sparse matrix object from an external package like `Matrix`.

```
> attributes(dtm)
$names
[1] "i"        "j"        "v"        "nrow"     "ncol"     "dimnames"

$class
[1] "DocumentTermMatrix"    "simple_triplet_matrix"

$Weighting
[1] "term frequency" "tf"
```

The dtm object has the i, j and v attributes which is the internal representation of your DocumentTermMatrix. Use:

```
library("Matrix") 
mat <- sparseMatrix(
           i=dtm$i,
           j=dtm$j, 
           x=dtm$v,
           dims=c(dtm$nrow, dtm$ncol)
           )
```

and you're done.

A naive comparison between your objects:

```
> mat[1,1:100]
> head(as.vector(dtm[1,]), 100)
```

will each give you the exact same output.

Answer (score 0):

DocumentTermMatrix uses [sparse matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix) representation, so it doesn't take up all that memory storing all those zeros. Depending what it is you want to do you might have some luck with the [SparseM](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SparseM/) package which provides some linear algebra routines using sparse matrices..

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Unfortunately SparseM does not seem like it is going to be helpful since I need calculate the Jaccard Similarity between each pair of lines. I do this by using the vegdist() function from the vegan package. This does not work on a sparse matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to increase the amount of RAM available to R? See this post: [Increasing (or decreasing) the memory available to R processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395229/increasing-the-memory-available-to-r-processes)

Also, sometimes when working with big objects in R, I occassionally call `gc()` to free up wasted memory.

Answer (score 0):

The number of documents should not be a problem but you may want to try removing sparse terms, this could very well reduce the dimension of document term matrix.

```
inspect(removeSparseTerms(dtm, 0.7))
```

It removes terms that has at least a sparsity of 0.7.

Another option available to you is that you specify minimum word length and minimum document frequency when you create document term matrix

```
a.dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(a.corpus, control = list(weighting = weightTfIdf, minWordLength = 2, minDocFreq = 5))
```

use `inspect(dtm)` before and after your changes, you will see huge difference, more importantly you won't ruin significant relations hidden in your docs and terms.

Answer (score 0):

Since you only have 1859 documents, the distance matrix you need to compute is fairly small.  Using the slam package (and in particular, its crossapply_simple_triplet_matrix function), you might be able to  compute the distance matrix directly, instead of converting the DTM into a dense matrix first.  This means that you will have to compute the Jaccard similarity yourself.  I have successfully tried [something similar for the cosine distance matrix on a large number of documents.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26149125/how-can-i-cluster-thousands-of-documents-using-the-r-tm-package)