# How to convert a doc-term matrix into a term-term matrix?

Tags: r, matrix, transformation, tm

```
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(reuters, control=list(wordLengths=c(1,Inf)))
```

I am thinking of turning dtm into a term-term matrix, what's below is incorrect:

```
dtm <- dtm %*% t(dtm)
```

How might it be done?

Comment: Have you checked out the answer to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7380133/1086688)?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the structure of a document-term matrix correctly, it is `t(dtm) %*% dtm`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10622730/constructing-a-co-occurrence-matrix-from-dummycoded-observations-in-r).

Answer (score 0):

I believe an approach as follows would work (note you are creating Boolean or maybe and adjacency matrix):

```
t(as.matrix(dtm)) %*% as.matrix(dtm)
```

For big dtm you will bounce into R's limits using `as.matrix`.  The `Matrix` package can help. Note I switch `i` and `j` to do the transpose in the first matrix.

```
data("acq")
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(acq, control=list(wordLengths=c(1,Inf)))
tdm <- t(dtm)

library(Matrix)
Xt <- sparseMatrix(j=dtm$i, i=dtm$j, x=dtm$v)
X <- sparseMatrix(j=tdm$i, i=tdm$j, x=tdm$v)

Xt %*% X

# For easier viewing
(Xt %*% X) [1:20, 1:20]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TDM <- TermDocumentMatrix(x) # Form a Term document matrix

termDocMatrix <- as.matrix(TDM) # convert your TDM into a matrix

termDocMatrix[termDocMatrix>=1] <- 1    # change the TDM into Boolean matrix

# term adjacency matrix
termMatrix <- termDocMatrix %*% t(termDocMatrix)


termMatrix[1:10,1:10]  # inspect terms numbered 1 to 10
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Please describe the answers more. when you have a link in your answer, it is probable that the page get removed and your answer get useless for other people in the future