# Memory allocation when using Shiny

Tags: r, memory-management, shiny

I am using Shiny to run a pretty simple simulation in **R**. However I run into problems with memory, and get the message:

> "Error: cannot allocate vector of size 274.8 Mb" etc.

But when I run the same code in **R Studio**, it works fine. Any general ideas how to increase the memory allocation to Shiny? Many thanks. Andrew.

Comment: Would it be possible to share your code as a gist on https://gist.github.com? I would love to help you get to the bottom of this. If you can't share your code publicly but can privately, please e-mail me at joe@rstudio.com.

Comment: @JoeCheng - Here is the code https://gist.github.com/4709926 Hopefully I have posted it correctly :) 
There are the ui.R and server.R files, as well as a file of functions that is called for the simulations (pest.tech.functions.R).

Answer (score 1):

Here are my standard links on memory management:
[R memory management / cannot allocate vector of size n Mb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171593/r-memory-management-cannot-allocate-vector-of-size-n-mb)

http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/Memory-limits.html

[Increasing (or decreasing) the memory available to R processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395229/increasing-the-memory-available-to-r-processes)

Comment: Thanks Alex. I should have said I had increased the memory.limit in R, but it still did not help. And because it runs fine when just using R on its own suggests that it is an issue I am having with Shiny rather than R per se.