# kmeans: Quick-TRANSfer stage steps exceeded maximum

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means

I am running k-means clustering in R on a dataset with 636,688 rows and 7 columns using the standard `stats` package: `kmeans(dataset, centers = 100, nstart = 25, iter.max = 20)`.

I get the following error: `Quick-TRANSfer stage steps exceeded maximum (= 31834400)`, and although one can view the code at http://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/library/stats/R/kmeans.R - I am unsure as to what is going wrong. I assume my problem has to do with the size of my dataset, but I would be grateful if someone could clarify once and for all what I can do to mitigate the issue.

Comment: I think it's more likely to do with the number of centers. Really? 100 clusters? Did you try a different algorithm, as in: `kmeans(dataset, algorithm="Lloyd", ...)`? That error message seems specific to the default algorithm, `Hartigan-Wong`.

Comment: @jlhoward - thanks! I then did try Lloyd and got no errors, although I really would prefer using Hartigan-Wong.

Comment: Note, the actual error flag is from here: http://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/library/stats/src/kmns.f (search `IFAULT = 4`). Still doesn't really explain what it means.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I just had the same issue.

See the documentation of kmeans in R via `?kmeans`:

> The Hartigan-Wong algorithm
>        generally does a better job than either of those, but trying
>        several random starts (‘nstart’> 1) is often recommended.  **In rare
>        cases, when some of the points (rows of ‘x’) are extremely close,
>        the algorithm may not converge in the “Quick-Transfer” stage**,
>        signalling a warning (and returning ‘ifault = 4’).  Slight
>        rounding of the data may be advisable in that case.

In these cases, you may need to switch to the Lloyd or MacQueen algorithms.

The nasty thing about R here is that it continues with a warning that may go unnoticed. For my benchmark purposes, I consider this to be a failed run, and thus I use:

```
if (kms$ifault==4) { stop("Failed in Quick-Transfer"); }
```

Depending on your use case, you may want to do something like

```
if (kms$ifault==4) { kms = kmeans(X, kms$centers, algorithm="MacQueen"); }
```

instead, to continue with a different algorithm.

If you are benchmarking K-means, note that R uses `iter.max=10` per default. It may take much more than 10 iterations to converge.

Comment: Here returns `res$ifault=0`, and not `res$ifault=4`, when the warning is thrown

Answer (score 14):

Had the same problem, seems to have something to do with available memory.

Running Garbage Collection before the function worked for me:

```
gc()
```

or reference:

[Increasing (or decreasing) the memory available to R processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395229/increasing-or-decreasing-the-memory-available-to-r-processes)

Answer (score 5):

@jlhoward's comment:

Try

```
kmeans(dataset, algorithm="Lloyd", ..)
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error message, but in my case it helped to increase the number of iterations iter.max. That contradicts the theory of memory overload.