# Blocked from accessing more memory in R despite having available memory in my system

Tags: windows, r, 64-bit, out-of-memory, rstudio

I am trying to access more memory using code I found in stackoverflow ([Increasing (or decreasing) the memory available to R processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395229/increasing-the-memory-available-to-r-processes)).  However, I get the following error which I haven't been able to resolve:

```
memory.limit(10000)

Error in memory.limit(10000) : 
don't be silly!: your machine has a 4Gb address limit
```

R is telling me that I have a 4gb address limit (despite the fact that I'm on a 64bit OS with 16gb of RAM).  Anyone know how to get around this?

Windows OS: Windows 7 Enterprise, Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2600 CPY @3.40GHz

Installed Memory (RAM): 16.0GB

System type: 64 bit OS

R Version: 3.0.0 
RStudio Version: 0.97.551

Comment: Are you using the 64bit version of R? Please provide the output of `sessionInfo()`.

Answer (score 1):

I never used R, but with a quick search I came across `memory.limit()`documentation ([here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/memory.size.html))

I quote :

> memory.limit(size = NA)
>   size : numeric. If NA report the memory size, otherwise request a new limit, in Mb.

10.000 MB = 10 GB, hence the error.

About the 64-bit problem, it may come from R itself (depending on the virtual machine version I guess).

Comment: My system has 16.0 GB (in excess of the 10GB I attempted to allocate) so I'm not sure why I'm getting the error.

Comment: @GaryLo if you are using a 32-bit version of R, you won't be able to address more than 4GB. Check it out.