# XLConnect output to Excel slow in MacBookPro. Why?

Tags: r, windows, macos, export-to-excel, xlconnect

Windows executes this code instantly but on my Mac it takes a long time, some times more than 10 minutes, just to write two data tables of around 2000 rows each. Can some one suggest a solution please? I have used XLConnect R library. Thanks.

```
# 8. Write results to file
path <- dirname(normalizePath(inp.file))
out.file <- paste(path, "/Out-",basename(inp.file),sep="")
wb <- loadWorkbook(out.file, create = TRUE)
createSheet(wb, name = "Activities")
createSheet(wb, name = "Resources")

writeWorksheet(wb, ActTab, sheet = "Activities", rownames = "EventNum")
writeWorksheet(wb, ResAvail, sheet = "Resources",rownames = "EventNum")
saveWorkbook(wb)
```

Comment: have you tried increasing the memory? they could be set differently http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395229/increasing-or-decreasing-the-memory-available-to-r-processes try `memory.limit()`

Comment: memory.limit() seems to be a Windows command, not osx?

Comment: did you type the command in R?

Comment: this is what I got
> memory.limit()
[1] Inf
Warning message:
'memory.limit()' is Windows-specific 
>

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I just cracked it. I deleted the output file from a previous run and it worked just fine. The problem seems to be with the option "create  = TRUE" in loadWorkbook function. Perhaps its not working as intended, to overwrite an existing file with the same name.

Comment: You should send this question and your observation to the package maintainer to see if it's reallly a bug.

Comment: create = TRUE works as intended here. create = TRUE will create a file if it does not yet exist but won't overwrite an existing one. Existing files will be loaded though.