# generate heatmap in R ( cannot allocate vector warning)

Tags: r, heatmap, regular-language

so I'm trying to generate a heatmap in R for gene expression analysis...
 I have 536 GB of memory in C, however when I tried to do a heatmap, it shows this message.

Error: cannot allocate vector of size 11.1 Gb
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In distfun(x) :
  Reached total allocation of 3544Mb: see help(memory.size)

how can i solve this, anyone? im running R in Windows OS, 64bit

Comment: possible duplicate of [Increasing (or decreasing) the memory available to R processes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395229/increasing-or-decreasing-the-memory-available-to-r-processes)

Answer (score 0):

I know that R has a memory limit, as can be seen [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Memory-limits.html), but it looks like you can override that using [memory.limit()](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/utils/memory.size)

Comment: i typed the memory.size() in R and it shows [1] 308.71.. what does that mean??

Comment: I typed in the wrong command, and edited it shortly after.

The result you got is : numeric. If NA report the memory limit, otherwise request a new limit, in Mb. Only values of up to 4095 are allowed on 32-bit R builds, but see ‘Details’.

So 308MB.

You need to use memory.limit(size=12200). That is 11.1GB + some extra space. 

I've never used it before, but I believe that should work.

You might also want to check out the link that @jeremycg posted in a comment. It is a little more thorough than my explanation.