# R: limiting the use of RAM

Tags: r, memory, ram

I am currently working with big fileList on R 64 bits, and my colleague is also using the same virtual machine with another software.

Because of the 64 bits version, R is using most of the available RAM (48 Go). I tried to limit it with memory.limit(X) with X the limit in MB.

I have the answer:

```
Warning message:
In memory.limit(4000) : cannot decrease memory limit: ignored
```

So I can not "decrease the memory"? I have tried different options (memory.size(max=FALSE), but I can not find a way to limit the maximum use of RAM at 24 GB for all sessions of R.

Any advice / help is welcome!

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1395256/1412059

Comment: I have tried this many times but it never worked... I wonder if there is a way to do it with a command.