# association rules in R not enough RAM

Tags: r, machine-learning, apriori

I have read all transactions from my datasat and then made apriori.
But I "ate" whole RAM.

It is possibble to omit this?
It is possible to prepare apriori without loading everything to RAM or
somehow merge the results?

Comment: I once used the R-package `ff` (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ff/index.html) and `biglm`(https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/biglm/index.html)
Is this what you are searching for?

Answer (score 2):

Generally, one can increase the memory available to R processes using command line parameters. See [Increasing (or decreasing) the memory available to R processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395229/increasing-or-decreasing-the-memory-available-to-r-processes)

However, `apriori` has some optimization options itself. Add a list of control parameters to your call to `apriori` using `control = list(memopt = TRUE)` to minimize memory usage and `control = list(load = FALSE)` to disable loading transactions into memory.