# Efficient way to do this double summation?

Tags: r

I have problem with the efficiency of the following code:

```
g=0

for (i in 1:n){

  for (j in 1:m){

    g=g+(as.numeric(x[i]>y[j])*as.numeric(z[i]<=a)*as.numeric(h[j]>a))

  }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please format your code and describe your problem in details

Comment: This code is doing exactly what it was written to do.

Comment: Dear, yes this code work perfectly, but it's computational time is very high. I need help to write this code in efficient way. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
t(h > a) %*% sapply(x, ">", y) %*% (z <= a)
```

Comment: For small data it works, but for my case I faced the following error message: Error: cannot allocate vector of size 18.6 Gb

Comment: This means you don't have enough memory on your system. I don't think there's any way to increase efficiency without constructing some intermediate vectors / matrices (which then take up memory) in order to utilize linear algebra libraries.  You may be able to increase the memory limit for R on your system. See

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395229/increasing-or-decreasing-the-memory-available-to-r-processes