# Change date to the end day of the month by data.table

Tags: r, date, memory-management, data.table

I have 4190145 observations.  And I want to change my date to the end day of the month. I explain in the following.

Here is my part of data:

```
Time1
2015/01/15
2015/02/24
2015/07/18
2015/11/10
2016/02/20
2016/04/26
2016/08/17
```

I want to create new column `Time2`:

```
Time1           Time2
2015/01/15      2015/01/31
2015/02/24      2015/02/28
2015/07/18      2015/07/31
2015/11/10      2015/11/30
2016/02/20      2016/02/29
2016/04/26      2016/04/30
2016/08/17      2016/08/31
```

The code is:

```
data[, Time2 := Time1]
day(data$Time2) <- days_in_month(data$Time1)
```

However, I got the error.

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size N Mb
```

Therefore, I search my problem on Stack Overflow and find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171593/r-memory-management-cannot-allocate-vector-of-size-n-mb).

I use `gc()` but still not work. So I see my `sessionInfo()`:

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] lubridate_1.6.0   data.table_1.10.4

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] lazyeval_0.2.0 R6_2.2.0       assertthat_0.1 magrittr_1.5   DBI_0.5-1      tools_3.3.3    dplyr_0.5.0    tibble_1.2    
 [9] Rcpp_0.12.9    stringi_1.1.2  stringr_1.1.0
```

I think it is because my computer just 32-bit. And `memory.limit()` can just set size to 4000 because my RAM is 4 GB.

Moreover, I figure out that if I use `data.table` to execute, I can run.

So, my problem is how to change my code from `day(data$Time2) <- days_in_month(data$Time1)` to `data.table` form.

Maybe like `data[, day(data$Time2) := days_in_month(data$Time1)]`  ?

I know this is incorrect because I get

> Error: Can't assign to the same column twice in the same query
>   (duplicates detected).

Any suggestion?

Comment: maybe you can split your data then run your original code and then `rbind` these separate data

Comment: What about `dt[,Time2:=as.Date(ISOdate(year(Time1), month(Time1), lubridate::days_in_month(Time1)))]`?

Comment: First step would be to use a date class, not POSIXlt or whatever is allowing you to use `/` and `day<-`; second, to prioritize making a reproducible example over posting session info and hardware details...

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395229/increasing-or-decreasing-the-memory-available-to-r-processes#comment1236220_1395256

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this works?

```
set.seed(120340)
NN = 5e6
DT = data.table(Time1 = 
                  sprintf('%04d/%02d/%02d',
                          sample(2000:2017, NN, TRUE),
                          sample(12, NN, TRUE),
                          sample(28, NN, TRUE)))

# potential memory bottleneck
DT[ , c('y', 'm', 'd') := tstrsplit(Time1, '/')]

days_month = data.table(
  month = sprintf('%02d', 1:12),
  days = c(31L, 28L, 31L, 30L, 31L, 30L, 
           31L, 31L, 30L, 31L, 30L, 31L)
)

DT[days_month, d_end := i.days, on = c(m = 'month')]
DT[m == 2L & as.integer(y) %% 4L == 0L, d_end := 29L]
DT[ , Time2 := do.call(paste, c(.SD, list(sep = '/'))), 
    .SDcols = c('y', 'm', 'd_end')]
```

If that fails, I guess this will be less memory-intensive:

```
DT[ , y := gsub('/.*', '', Time1)]
DT[ , c('m', 'd') := tstrsplit(Time1, '/')[2L:3L], by = y]
```

And if that fails, I suggest buying more RAM, or working with a subset of your data before deploying to a more serious machine. Also, as Frank points out, you really want to be storing these as `IDates` for maximal memory efficiency.

Comment: If they're facing a reasonably small date range (like spanning under 1000 years), they could enumerate the end-o-months and use a rolling join, maybe... assuming they actually used dates instead of strings.

Comment: @Frank yea, I thought of that. I figured this way is similar in terms of memory requirements and speed, but easier to see the logic. But joining my `days_month` here to `CJ(yr = unique(DT$y), mo = 1:12)` is another option to try.

Comment: Yeah, I guess it's just perspective. As someone who hates working with dates / learning their minutiae, I find rolling on `seq(as.IDate("1900-01-01"), as.IDate("2100-01-01"), by="month")-1L` easier to follow.

Comment: @Frank ah gotcha. I had something slightly different in mind. Actually 1900 is the one year in there that's annoying because of `as.Date('1900-03-01') - 1L` being unexpected

Comment: actually, `data.table` still has limit. If data is very big, it gets error as well.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, here is what I would do using `data.table` and `lubridate`:

```
# create sample data
library(data.table)
set.seed(120340)
NN <- 1e6
DT <- data.table(Time1 = sprintf('%04d/%02d/%02d',
                                 sample(2000:2017, NN, TRUE),
                                 sample(12, NN, TRUE),
                                 sample(28, NN, TRUE)))
```

#### Using `ceiling_date()`

```
library(lubridate)
DT[, Time2 := ceiling_date(ymd(Time1), "month") - 1]
DT
```

> ```
>               Time1      Time2
>       1: 2005/04/14 2005-04-30
>       2: 2007/01/11 2007-01-31
>       3: 2014/09/08 2014-09-30
>       4: 2017/05/13 2017-05-31
>       5: 2008/05/23 2008-05-31
>      ---                      
>  999996: 2003/06/08 2003-06-30
>  999997: 2004/04/12 2004-04-30
>  999998: 2009/06/10 2009-06-30
>  999999: 2013/02/04 2013-02-28
> 1000000: 2014/03/05 2014-03-31
> ```

```
tables()
```

> ```
>      NAME      NROW NCOL MB COLS        KEY
> [1,] DT   1,000,000    2 16 Time1,Time2    
> Total: 16MB
> ```

Using `data.table`'s assignment operator `:=` updates `DT` by reference, i.e., without copying the whole data object.

`ceiling_date()` *takes a date-time object and rounds it up to the nearest boundary of the specified time unit*, i.e., to the first day of the next month. Therefore, we have to subtract 1 day to get the last day of the actual month.

#### Reducing memory footprint with `as.IDate()`

`data.table` has its own date and time classes with integer storage for fast sorting and grouping. Integer storage `may` require less memory than `double` on some systems:

```
DT[, Time1 := as.IDate(Time1, "%Y/%m/%d")]
DT[, Time2 := as.IDate(ceiling_date(ymd(Time1), "month") - 1)]
tables()
```

> ```
>      NAME      NROW NCOL MB COLS        KEY
> [1,] DT   1,000,000    2  8 Time1,Time2    
> Total: 8MB
> ```

Here, only half the memory is required.