# How to manually allocate memory in an R session?

Tags: r

Is it possible to manually allocate memory in an R session? I work on a shared windows server that sometimes runs into memory issues. When using Stata is it possible to allocate memory for that session with:

```
set min_memory 50g
```

There is something similar in R?

---

#### Edit to provide better context:

Why would I need such a command?

Let's say we have a script that peaks the RAM usage at 20Gb but only uses 5Gb most of the time. The natural way that R handle this is to allocate the memory only as needed( which in most cases seems reasonable). But imagine you need to run this program on a shared server( with a lot more RAM than that) that can, due to other users needs, not have 20Gb free memory at the point the program peaks.

In that situation I think would be nice to avoid such a risk by previous allocating the 20Gb you will need for that R session( as it is possible in Stata) when starting the program, and then avoiding to waste resources in a run that will not even finish.

Comment: `memory.limit()`

Comment: @HFBrowning `memory.limit()` returns the maximum allocation( in most cases the total RAM of your computer). I would like to *change* the *minimun* memory ( the amount of memory allocated to the process). It would be something equivalent to creating a big fake object that uses the memory and then deleting it when it is needed( so no other process or user could have used it first).

Comment: @HFBrowning That would change the maximum amount of memory that the r session can allocate, wich is not what I am trying to do.

Comment: I don't think I'm really following how what you want to do is different than what `memory.limit()` can accomplish - have you looked at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395229/increasing-or-decreasing-the-memory-available-to-r-processes ?

Comment: @HFBrowning  Yes, I looked into it, thanks for the reference. `memory.limit()` is just a option for the maximum memory that your r session can allocate, it will be the same unless you change it, even if another process is using 99% of the RAM. It could be that the limit is less than the actual memory available so change it will solve the problem but is not my case. I would like to previous allocate an amount of memory so no other process can use it.

Comment: @HFBrowning I haved edited the question to provide better context on why would I need such a command, and maybe that clarifies why I think `memory.limit()` do not help

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, that makes a lot more sense. This is actually a very good question! I'll do a little digging to see what I can find, and maybe someone else knows

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR:** I did a lot of digging and could not find anything that even hinted at a "minimum memory size" setting.

If I understand your question correctly, you would like to have R request a very large (20 Gb) amount of memory up front for a session and then manage this memory on its own in order to ensure that resources are available when needed. From what I have been able to gather, this is not possible and it is approximately the opposite of the strategy employed by R’s designers.

As you have stated, R allocates and manages memory by:

1. Setting a max limit for the session
2. Allocating as objects are created
3. Within certain limits, reclaiming memory as soon as the object is done

For small allocations, I *think* step 3 is done using the C function `alloca()` which uses the stack and for larger ones it uses `malloc()` which allocates on the heap. What this *effectively* means is that R can request a small pool of memory (128 bytes, according to [Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html)) to manage itself for small objects that come and go pretty quickly, but for larger objects it lets the operating system handle it.

All of the focus I have seen from comments in the source and [R internals](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html#Memory-allocators) suggests that the dev team was focused on writing software that would only hold the amount of memory needed for current computation and then promptly release it:

> We want the heap sizes to get set at levels adequate for the current
>   computations.  The present mechanism uses only the size of the current
>   live heap to provide information about the current needs; since the
>   current live heap size can be very volatile, the adjustment mechanism
>   only makes gradual adjustments.  A more sophisticated strategy would
>   use more of the live heap history (lines 314 – 320 in [source](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/main/memory.c))

That being said, there could be a package or extension that has re-written some of this core functionality that I am not aware of – although this seems like such a dramatic departure from the way R was written it would probably be a fork of the project rather than a package. If you are not interested in doing that yourself, I would recommend a more mundane solution, like running your program overnight to avoid competition for resources. Or incrementally processing your data, or seeing if something like a database or the `bigmemory` package could help you. Good luck!