# Managing memory.size() with foreach parallel threads in R

Tags: r, memory, memory-management, foreach, parallel-processing

When I run `memory.size(max=NA)` I get:  `[1] 16264`

But `memory.size(max=T)` gives me `[1] 336.88`

When I look at Task Manager, the 4 threads are using a total of ~1,000 MB (1/16 of my 16GB of available RAM) but they are using 100% of my CPU.  While running, all processes combined are only using 50% of my 16GB of available RAM.

Whenever I try to increase memory allocation with `memory.size(max=1000)`, I get the warning message:

```
Warning message:
In memory.size(max = 1000) : cannot decrease memory limit: ignored
```

What is going on here?

1) Is my CPU just slow given the amount of RAM I have? (Intel i7-6500U 2.5 GHz)

2) Does memory allocation require additional steps when using parallel threading?  (e.g. `doParallel`)

Comment: Answers are great on this post
The first answer gives a great link that advice to set the memory limit from the command processor and not directly R 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395229/increasing-or-decreasing-the-memory-available-to-r-processes

Comment: I actually found this post, but the link you mention is now dead

Comment: Not the mirror link: https://web.archive.org/web/20091208054821/http://gking.harvard.edu/zelig/docs/How_do_I2.html

Comment: @MaxFt Tried it and I get "name [...] specified in target box is not valid.  Make sure the path and file name are correct."