# how to increase my memory limit in R studio

Tags: r, memory, rstudio

```
chkk <- binom.krige(chkt, locations=plt$coords, 
                    krige=krige.glm.control(type.krige="ok", 
                                            cov.pars=c(f1$psill[2], f1$range[2]),
                                            cov.model="sph", 
                                            trend.d=~chktrend[, -1],
                                            trend.l=~trendl[, -1]), 
                    mcmc.input=mcmc.control(burn.in=5000, n.iter=10000, 
                                            S.scale=0.0035, thin=10))
```

Above is my interpolation command which i want to run, my PC have 64 GB of RAM but when i run this code it consume only 12GB, is their any option to use and my code run fast by using maximum memory of RAM
Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395229/increasing-or-decreasing-the-memory-available-to-r-processes

Comment: memory.limit() is the command to check the available ram n you can change is using memory.limit(size =)

Comment: yes i checked these commands but it didn't work

Comment: it say you  cannot decrease memory limit , i mean the limit it give me is already at maximum