# How to allocate enough memory to join datasets in R

Tags: r, rstudio

On my oc win10 RAM: 8Mbytes
using RStudio, 
trying to left join two datasets gives the following error:

```
> final_df <- whole_data %>% left_join(zones,by=c("Country_Transco"))
```

Error: cannot allocate vector of size 4.6 Mb

```
> final_df <- zones %>% left_join(whole_data,by=c("Country_Transco"))
```

Error: cannot allocate vector of size 2.3 Mb

How to allocate enough memory to join datasets in R, 
given that Rstudio already takes Gb 
and the whole system style have 2 Gbytes free ?

Even better: using a unique key for the join:

```
final_df = merge(x = zones, y = whole_data, by.x =  c("Country_Transco","region"), by.y = c("Country_Transco","region"), all.x = TRUE)
```

Error: cannot allocate vector of size 681 Kb

memory.limit() returns

```
> memory.limit()
[1] 8086
```

(8Gb)

Comment: A duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/1395229/5784831?

Comment: Changed my windows version of RStudio from RStudio-1.1.383 to RStudio-1.1.463.
No memory limit is reached now.