# Can't install package due to address limit while there is enough memory available (non-zero exit status)

Tags: r, memory-management, devtools

I'm trying to install the urbnmapr package from github in RStudio but am getting an error that my PCs address limit is too small while there is lots of memory available. I've already tried the solution provided [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395229/increasing-or-decreasing-the-memory-available-to-r-processes).

I'm using   `devtools::install_github("UrbanInstitute/urbnmapr")`
and getting the following console prints:

```
Downloading GitHub repo UrbanInstitute/urbnmapr@master
√  checking for file 'C:\Users\***********\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpSOQbWK\remotes13fc75a94529\UrbanInstitute-urbnmapr-21be5c2/DESCRIPTION' ... 
-  preparing 'urbnmapr': (369ms)
√  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... 
-  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
-  checking for empty or unneeded directories
-  looking to see if a 'data/datalist' file should be added
-  building 'urbnmapr_0.0.0.9002.tar.gz' (3.8s)

* installing *source* package 'urbnmapr' ...
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
  converting help for package 'urbnmapr'
    finding HTML links ... done
    ccdf_labels                             html  
    counties                                html  
    counties_labels                         html  
    countydata                              html  
    get_urbn_labels                         html  
    get_urbn_map                            html  
    statedata                               html  
    states                                  html  
    states_labels                           html  
    territories_counties                    html  
    territories_labels                      html  
*** copying figures
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
*** arch - i386
Error in utils::memory.limit(104000) : 
  don't be silly!: your machine has a 4Gb address limit
Execution halted
*** arch - x64
ERROR: loading failed for 'i386'
* removing 'E:/Programme/R-3.5.3/library/urbnmapr'
In R CMD INSTALL
Error in i.p(...) : 
  (converted from warning) installation of package ‘C:/Users/***********/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpSOQbWK/file13fc71237900/urbnmapr_0.0.0.9002.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

As you can see from this error: `Error in utils::memory.limit(104000) : 
  don't be silly!: your machine has a 4Gb address limit
Execution halted` my memory is definitely big enough but still stops the installation. My `sessionInfo()` is as follows:

```
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
[5] LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.2        rstudioapi_0.10   magrittr_1.5      usethis_1.5.0    
 [5] devtools_2.0.2    pkgload_1.0.2     R6_2.4.0          rlang_0.4.0      
 [9] tools_3.5.3       pkgbuild_1.0.3    sessioninfo_1.1.1 cli_1.1.0        
[13] withr_2.1.2       remotes_2.0.4     yaml_2.2.0        assertthat_0.2.1 
[17] digest_0.6.20     rprojroot_1.3-2   crayon_1.3.4      processx_3.3.1   
[21] callr_3.2.0       fs_1.3.1          ps_1.3.0          curl_3.3         
[25] memoise_1.1.0     glue_1.3.1        compiler_3.5.3    desc_1.2.0       
[29] backports_1.1.4   prettyunits_1.0.2
```

For additional info I'm using a single pagefile to increase my memory limit, but have plenty of memory to allocate more than 4Gb without it and afaik 64-bit Windows 10 should very much be able to have a higher address limit than this. I have 32GB of dRAM installed using an Intel i7-6700K which supports up to 64GB of dRAM. 
Would be glad for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED, posting in case someone else has the same problem.

To use the pagefile as memory for large data I used `invisible(utils::memory.limit(104000))` in my .Rprofile, removing this and starting RStudio without without loading my environment (i.e. a different, smaller project or a new file) and just installing the packages in that session didn't throw the error and the installs worked. Re-upped the memory.limit and restarted R afterwards, everything works as it should.