# Is it possible to increase memory limit in R

Tags: r, regression

I have added three interaction terms to a regression. I have an error saying

> Error: cannot allocate vector of size 2.6 Gb

Is it possible to increase the memory?

Also is the vector the `grid4` variable or the model, `full`?

```
lm(lw~expr*kww + expr*iq + expr*unemployment_years, train60) -> full

grid4 <- train60 %>% data_grid(expr, kww, iq, unemployment_years) %>% add_predictions(full)
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer you question directly, yes it is possible [to increase memory size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395229/increasing-or-decreasing-the-memory-available-to-r-processes).
However, when I get this kind of error it usually has do to something in the code/mutation I want to preform. As you did not provide an input it is hard to reproduce.

Comment: I can provide the full code, but it's is lengthy and in rmarkdown? Is that okay?

Comment: best practice is to create a minimal reproducible example:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example