# How do count unique entities with disk.frame in R?

Tags: r, disk.frame

I'd like to convert a data frame to a disk frame and then count the first column. It's not counting the number of unique values of the column when I try it. It appears to be counting the number of workers.

```
library(disk.frame)
options(future.globals.maxSize = Inf)
setup_disk.frame(workers = 8)
```

This is an example dataset

```
    bigint <- sample(123901239804:901283455390, 3*10^5)
    df <- data.frame(bigint)
    df %>% 
      summarize(ints = length(unique(bigint)))
    
    df %>% 
      as.disk.frame %>%
      summarize(ints = length(bigint)) %>% 
      collect
```

In the first query, it gets me this output

```
    ints
1 300000
```

In the second query, it gets me this output

```
    ints
1      8
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

{disk.frame} only supports some group-by functions. You can use `dplyr::n_distinct`

```r
df %>% 
  as.disk.frame %>%
  summarize(ints = n_distinct(bigint)) %>% 
  collect
```

which yields

```
    ints
1 300000
```

See the list of supported group-by verbs here https://diskframe.com/articles/10-group-by.html#list-of-supported-group-by-functions

You can define more customised group-by verbs by following this guide

https://diskframe.com/articles/11-custom-group-by.html

Certain groups-by verbs are not possible to be done in an exact way (and has to rely on estimates) due to the chunking-nature of disk.frame. But that is true of all "big" data systems.

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to use disk frame for this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63800688/choosing-the-right-approach-for-a-50gb-file

Comment: Is it possible to calculate a given percentile for a column?

Comment: @Cauder it's in the list of group-by verbs :) But it's not exact, rather it's an approximate.

Comment: Thank you! Are there any articles comparing disk.frame and data table? I'd love to learn more about when I should be using one approach against the other approach

Comment: @Cauder read the common questions. data.table is pure in memory, while disk.frame is on disk. So disk.frame is slower but can handle any data that fits on your disk. See https://diskframe.com/#common-questions

Comment: That's awesome. To put it back to you, disk frame can work with larger datasets because there's more resources on disk than in memory. But, if something fits in memory, then maybe data table is an acceptable solution

Comment: disk.frame() looks sweet. Can I pass it a folder of CSV files?

Comment: @Cauder yes. See https://diskframe.com/articles/04-ingesting-data.html#multiple-csv-files Better ask questions here https://github.com/xiaodaigh/disk.frame/issues