# Choosing the right approach for a 50GB file

Tags: r, datatable

I'm pulling data that will result in a file that has about 1.5B rows.

I'm thinking about what system I should use to analyze the data. The data has a pretty simple structure.

I'm considering working with the data with either a distributed system like Spark or an R system like DataTables.

Assuming I'm on a machine with lots of memory, can I work with a 50GB / 1.5B row dataset with DataTables in R?

Comment: Maybe I can reduce the file-size by reducing the no. of columns I'm working with at any one time

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use `fread()`, from the **data.table** package. You can follow something like this:

1. Load a few rows of the data to analyze it. If you want to load it as a **dataframe** class object, instead of a **data table**, you can set the argument `data.table = FALSE`.

```
df = fread(file = , nrows = 10, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

2. Take a quick look at the data table and define classes for each column in a vector. You should also check whether you can skip some rows or columns.

```
classes = c('numeric', 'character', ...)
rows = c(1:1000, 20000:50000, ...)
cols = c(1, 6, 8, ...)
```

3. Load the whole data, skipping rows and columns, if possible, and defining the class of each column of interest.

```
df = fread(file = , drop = -cols, colClasses = classes, nrows = rows)
```

Ps.: if your memory ram still can't stock the whole data, build up a function to read, process and write the data, and call it several multiple times, using the **nrows** argument to split the data into fragments.

Answer (score 1):

You can use {disk.frame}, see https://diskframe.com

It's designed for problems like this.

Comment: I know that data tables works with references. When I manipulate an object in disk frame, am I creating a copy of it or changing its reference? For instance, if I use `hard_arrange`, am I creating a duplicate of the object and then trashing the old one?

Comment: Better ask questions there https://github.com/xiaodaigh/disk.frame/issues