# R question: What parts of a computer should be upgraded when the "View" command stutter?

Tags: r, view

Recently, I have a problem to use R.
Whenever I use very huge data set, the "View" command stutter.
What I mean is that initially, only one-fifth of the data appears on the screen, and no data values appear immediately on the screen as I browse the data.

In this case, if I add an extra SSD memory, can I improve this situation? or other parts of my computer such as graphic card are needed to upgrade?
What parts should be upgraded in this case?

Thank you for your time spent to read this question.

Comment: This previous answer may help you. [Increasing (or decreasing) the memory available to R processes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1395229/4752675)

Comment: You should just stop viewing huge data. Learn to subset and summarize data. What exactly do you hope to achieve by looking at data with a few million rows (I assume that's what you mean by "very huge")?