# R：how to solve the problem about allocating space

Tags: r

With WGCNA,I run a command,TOMsimilarity,but it shows,Unable to allocate a vector of size 4.9 Gb,but I have enough space.
[image]

Comment: what about ```memory.limit(size = ..)```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Increasing (or decreasing) the memory available to R processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395229/increasing-or-decreasing-the-memory-available-to-r-processes)