# Cannot allocate a vector of memory 1.6 GB when mergin dataframs

Tags: r, memory, merge

I'm trying to merge a 5 millions rows 10 col df with a 600 k row and 145 cols df  on a few columns :

```
calculs_user <- inner_join(calculs_user,champs_diag, by=c("ID.user" = "ID.user","Date" = "Date", "Year" = "Year", "Form" = "Form"))
```

but the error "cannot allocate a vector of size 1.6 GB" keeps running. I'm working on a 16 GB Ram machine and 64-bit R and I tried to follow solutions in [R memory management / cannot allocate vector of size n Mb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171593/r-memory-management-cannot-allocate-vector-of-size-n-mb) , but it does not work. My memory size limit is set to 16 GB so I don't understand why 1.6 GB would be too much !

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Increasing (or decreasing) the memory available to R processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395229/increasing-or-decreasing-the-memory-available-to-r-processes)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion, but I already set the memory.limit() to 160 GB. This does not change the error. I think my machine is just not powerful enough.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `data.table` while trying to free RAM as much as possible? `dplyr` is a great package, but it does have issues when dealing with huge datasets. In my experience, `data.table` performs better in this regard.
It is also worth pointing out that the function `gc()` does not entirely free unused RAM, so you might want to restart RStudio before trying to run the code.

Here is an example of code you could try that I cannot properly test (as I do not have your data):

```
library(data.table)

calculs_user = as.data.table(calculs_user)
champs_diag = as.data.table(champs_diag)

calculs_user = calculs_user[champs_diag, on = c("ID.user", "Date", "Year", "Form"), nomatch = 0]
```

If this does not work, you ccould try using [ff package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ff/index.html), that should trick R into thinking that you use RAM while you are not, but I never used it myself.

And, of course, if everything else fails, you can divide your data into smaller chunks. It might become tedious if you need to do it a lot, though. But still, it is an option.