# group by three variables in very large data frame

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, bigdata, large-data

I have a very large data frame in r with 4.3 million rows and 7 columns which I need to group and summarize in order to create some graphics (with ggplot) later on. But it seems that this isn't working, I waited for a couple hours, but nothing happend.

I have an example with a small data frame that works:

```
SDO_ID <- c(44, 44, 44, 44, 45, 45, 45, 45)
Value <- c(93,94,88,77,68,51,55,78)
zeitstempel <- c("2018-01-01 01:00:00", "2018-01-01 02:00:00", "2018-01-02 01:00:00", "2018-01-02 02:00:00")
time <- format(as.POSIXct(zeitstempel),format = "%H:%M:%S")
date <- as.Date(zeitstempel)
df <- data.frame(SDO_ID, Value, time, date)

rf_by_day <- df %>% group_by(date, SDO_ID) %>%
  summarize(value = mean(Value))
```

This example works as expected. But with my original data frame (over 4.3 million rows) I don't get any result. Do I just have to wait longer? Or is there anything that I could do to improve the code?

Would it help if I first extract the months and then use the months for grouping instead of the exact date (since there will be fewer rows in the final data frame)? Or does this not make any difference, since the original data frame has 4.3 million rows anyways?

Thank you!

Comment: When you run only `group_by()`, how many groups do you have? Perhaps a data.table approach would suit you better

Comment: i think data.table is faster than tidy at somepoint. You can try it. 
`rf_bay_day[, mean(Value), by = c('date','SDI_ID')]`

Comment: You should add a ")" here:  group_by(date, SDO_ID)

Comment: Then it could help to increase the memory of R. I had the same issue with large data. See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395229/increasing-or-decreasing-the-memory-available-to-r-processes
If your code is working with a small df, it just needs time. Increasing the available memory for calculation could make it faster.

Comment: Thank you all! The `data.table` tip helped. (I actually thought the original was a `data.table` because I used `fread`, but it tured out, it wasn't due to things I did later.)