# how to avoid " out of memory " in shiny server in a rgl using app

Tags: r, shiny, rgl

I am trying to run a rgl shiny app, it works well on my computer but crashes on [www.shinyapps.io](http://www.shinyapps.io).

I suspect that the 1GB memory is not enough as the  shinyapps.io log tells me `Container event from container-8564782: oom (out of memory)`.

It is 6 triangle3d() relatively complex objects in one rglwidget(). A button create a new translation of these 6 objects and plot it in a new rgl object. I tried to put `lit=FALSE` in the object to save memory, but it still crashes (not always though).
I also suspect that the rgl object is not erased from memory when creating a new one. So I tried rglwidget options (`reuse=NA, webGLoptions = list(preserveDrawingBuffer = FALSE)`), but deploying for testing is not very efficient...

- Is there a way to test the app locally with the same 1GB memory?
- Are there other obvious ways to save memory when using rgl/shiny?

Any pointer welcome!

https://colomb.shinyapps.io/RANDOMstage/
core of the code:

```
observe({ 
    input$randomise 
    #### Create a random position of each objects using translate3d, plot them using triangle3d.
    amessage = random_obj( objects= objects, position_tot =position_tot, messagesday=messagesday, colorpalette=palette("Okabe-Ito"))
    
    output$rglPlot <- renderRglwidget({
      
      createboden()
      
      view3d (theta = 0, phi = -88, zoom = 0.8, fov = 60)
      outputwidget = rglwidget(reuse=NA, webGLoptions = list(preserveDrawingBuffer = FALSE))
      
      
      outputwidget

    
    })
```

Comment: "Is there a way to test the app locally with the same 1GB memory?"  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395229/increasing-or-decreasing-the-memory-available-to-r-processes

Comment: Please show reproducible code.  We can't suggest improvements if we don't know what you did.

Comment: Thanks. the memory question is only answered for windows user, also not sure whether memory for R would mean memory for shiny.
reproducible code is here difficult, I do not want to make the code public at this point (the objects are not mine to share), and the memory issue would not appear in a simplified example.

Answer (score 0):

A major issue was the size of the objects. As objects were STL objects read via `readSTL()`, I minimised the complexity of the object first using a third party software. (https://3dless.com, objects went from 6MB to 100 kB).
It now uses much less memory and runs on the server.